# Questions on energy conservation of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I'm reading [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130304174) book. In Ch. 3.4, it studies the wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ with BCs $u_x(0,t)=0,\,u_x(L,t)=0$, and ICs $u(x,0)=f(x),\,u_t(x,0)=g(x)$.

The total energy of a string is the summation of the kinetic energy and the potential energy: $E=E_k+E_p=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Lu_t^2dx+\frac{c^2}{2}\int_0^Lu_x^2dx$. I know that $E_k=mv^2/2$ and $E_p=kx^2/2$.

However, in the integral, $E_k$ term does not contain mass and the $E_p$ term has $u_x^2$ in stead of the square of the displacement. How can I figure out the unit and the dimension?

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer without having the book. Anyway, in this kind of mathematical works it is very common to normalize constants to $1$, thus losing the possibility of doing dimensional analysis but simplifying formulas a bit.

Comment: Anyway, [this might be useful](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16755/why-is-energy-in-a-wave-proportional-to-amplitude-squared). Note that the term with $u_x^2$ accounts for the *deformation* of an element of the string, not its displacement. The string gains potential energy by deforming itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wondered similar things myself many times in the past ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40623/8157) an example). Mathematical books usually simplify physical constants to $1$, and moreover, they occasionally abuse of language. (Example. The word "energy" is one of the most common in mathematics, but [it does not always match its physical meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39822/8157)).

> However, here the "energy" you mentioned really is the same energy a
>   physicist would talk about. [At this
>   link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16755/why-is-energy-in-a-wave-proportional-to-amplitude-squared)
>   I gave my 2 cents on this fact. This is explained in a (IMHO)
>   clear way in the classic physics book by Halliday (first volume, section 18.4 of the Italian translation - I hope that the numbering does not change from the original version of the book). That's where I took
>   the formulas in the linked post.

Note that the "dimensionally correct" equation for a vibrating string is

$$ \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - T\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=0,$$

with the notations of the linked post (i.e. $\mu=$ mass density, $T=$ tension). This is dimensionally consistent: $u$ is a displacement, so 
$$
[u]=L, $$
("dimension of $u$ is Length"), $\mu$ is a mass density, so 
$$
[\mu]=ML^{-1}$$
("mass times length$^{-1}$"), and $T$ is tension, which is a force, so 
$$
[T]=MLt^{-2}$$
("mass times length times time$^{-2}$"). Therefore 
$$
\left[ \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \right] = Mt^{-2} = \left[ T\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \right].$$

The equation you wrote, that is 
$$
u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx}=0$$
corresponds to this one with 
$$
c=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}.$$
You can check that this $c$ has the dimensions of speed: $[c]=Lt^{-1}$.